# Array.sort method not working when sorting by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a basic array, that I'm trying to sort by the `source` property:

```js
const arr = [
    { source: '64', target: '63' },
    { source: '61', target: '64' },
    { source: '114', target: '63' },
];

console.log('before', arr);

arr.sort(
    (a, b) => a.source > b.source
        // move element to a lower index
        ? -1
            // move element to a higher index
            : b.source > a.source
            ? 1
        : 0);
        
console.log('after', arr);
```

But this leaves the array untouched. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In the sort function you are comparing the `source` property as a string instead of as a number try parsing `a.source` and `b.source` to Number

Comment: try that - `arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.source) - parseInt(b.source))`

Comment: Even without parsing I guess it would work fine...```arr.sort((a, b) => a.source-b.source);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple way of doing this

You can do it directly without condition inside sort

```js
const arr = [{
    source: '64',
    target: '63'
  },
  {
    source: '61',
    target: '64'
  },
  {
    source: '114',
    target: '63'
  },
];

console.log('before', arr);

arr.sort((a, b) => a.source - b.source); // ascending
//arr.sort((a, b) => b.source - a.source); // descending

console.log('after', arr);
```

#### Way of doing this by conversion

Or you can convert string to number, without extra conditions inside your sort

```js
const arr = [{
    source: '64',
    target: '63'
  },
  {
    source: '61',
    target: '64'
  },
  {
    source: '114',
    target: '63'
  },
];

console.log('before', arr);

arr.sort((a, b) => Number(a.source) > Number(b.source) ? -1 : 1);

console.log('after', arr);
```

Comment: `arr.sort((a, b) => a.source - b.source);` seems to work, `b.source - a.source` does not

Comment: sorry @Mike I thought you want  descending not ascending  :), fixed

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert strings to integers, before making comparisons, otherwise non-empty string will coerce to true and you are basically doing `true > true` inside your sort resolver.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use numbers for the `source` value or coerce them to numbers, as below:

```js
const arr = [
    { source: '64', target: '63' },
    { source: '61', target: '64' },
    { source: '114', target: '63' },
];

console.log('before', arr);

arr.sort(
    (a, b) => Number(a.source) > Number(b.source)
        // move element to a lower index
        ? -1
            // move element to a higher index
            : Number(b.source) > Number(a.source)
            ? 1
        : 0);
        
console.log('after', arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over complicating it.

```
arr.sort((a,b) => a.source - b.source);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your strings in the array to numbers.

```js
const arr = [
    { source: 64, target: 63 },
    { source: 61, target: 64 },
    { source: 114, target: 63 },
];

console.log('before', arr);

arr.sort(
    (a, b) => a.source > b.source
        // move element to a lower index
        ? -1
            // move element to a higher index
            : b.source > a.source
            ? 1
        : 0);
        
console.log('after', arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your sorting works.**

You sort the array by string and descending

```
'64'
'61'
'114'
```

and because of having this sorting in your data, nothings happens.

For sorting the values ascending as strings swap `1` and `-1`.

To get a result of numerical order convert either the values to number or use an implicit conversion by using a numerical operator, like `-`.

```
(a, b) => a.source - b.source // ascending
(a, b) => b.source - a.source // descending
```